# discord.py bot says function doesn't exist while it does

Tags: python, discord.py

I was about to start making a discord bot with python when it didn't recognize a function i made.
The first minor problem I found was that when I made my `async def on_ready()` function, it didn't print anything while i did tell it to `print("Bot is online.")`.

The second problem is that when I run the command `!verify`, it throws this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "verify" is not found`

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online.")

async def verify(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Member")
    if role not in ctx.message.author.roles:
        print("NOT A MEMBER.")
    else:
        print("IS A MEMBER.")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `client.command()` decorator to let **discord.py** know that it is a command:

```py
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Member")
    if role not in ctx.message.author.roles:
        print("NOT A MEMBER.")
    else:
        print("IS A MEMBER.")
```

Also write `@client.event` before your `on_ready` function because it is a **discord.py** event.

Comment: Oh yes I totally forgot about that! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @zenof Then could you accept my answer, please? (If it was helpful)

Comment: Of course, I was waiting for the 10 minutes to be over :)

Comment: @zenof Thank you!